# Connecting to a minecraft server, Displaying chat

Tags: minecraft

Is it possible to create a jar file that when executed will connect to a server IP then read chat. It would not be a client, just run in terminal. I believe this is possible, I just need to know the name of what it is called so I can look it up xD

EDIT:
This will also need to run on a raspberry pi

Comment: Something that connects to a server? Sounds like a client.

Comment: Gotta run on a raspberry pi, Clients wont :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely possible through use of the Minecraft protocol seen here: http://wiki.vg/Protocol

You will need to do a few things to simulate a client.

1. Log into the minecraft service and keep track of auth data.
2. Log in to the server using the given protocol and your known profile.
3. Respond to incoming "are you there" messages from the server.
4. Read incoming chat messages from the server and output to command line. (Involves color parsing and other stuff if you want the real experience)

All of the documentation on the protocol for each packet is available on that wiki. Just open a socket that knows how to deal with that information and you should be fine.

EDIT: If you own the server that you wish to do this for, you could alternatively create a bukkit plugin to send chat through a simpler socket and just read straight from that.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, "Protocol". Thanks very much :D

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to make a wrapper for the minecraft client.  I just made a wrapper for my bucket server which basically launches the .jar file with a "-nogui" command option then redirects output to a richtextbox.  If the client supports a -nogui option you might be able to do the same.

Comment: Alright sounds good, I dont think that will run on my raspberry pi though :(

Comment: Ah, sorry.  Didn't know about that pre-req.  I used c# for my gui wrapper but I'm not sure what options the pi OS offers.  If I understand right, they're just light-weight linux distro's so maybe something in Python or Java.